# how to exclude the files while build using Grunt task

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, karma-jasmine

I have the following task in grunt.

```
    app_files : {
            js : [ 'src/**/*.js', '!src/**/*.unitTest.js']
    }
```

and other

```
    bb_app_files : {
            js : [ 'src/appbb/**/*.js', '!src/appbb/**/*.unitTest.js' ]
    }
```

I have two grunt tasks to build two separate concatenated JS files. In the first app_files test files are getting excluded but in the second one bb_app_files test files are not excluding.

Comment: Try using exclude = [];

Comment: `!` at the beginning of a pattern will negate the match.

Comment: Seems correct at first glance - please post a little more of your Gruntfile (for example: what task are you running, is `js` a variable or a parameter?). And can you list the names of some files that are not excluded?